# How to make facebook authentication pop-ups using python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm using [social-auth-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) with FacebookOAuth2 backend what is based on [python-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth) and trying to set `display=popup` at  facebook authentication trought app settings.

Found [this](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/issues/148) old issue for [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) what is deprecated in favor of python-social-auth, but that options doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below line to your settings

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {
    'display': 'popup',
}

I found out it from the source code:
https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/backends/base.py#L203